# Beginner C programming

Tags: c, nested-loops

I'm trying to find all the numbers that add up to 10. I'm using a nested for loop. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() { 
int i = 0; 
int j = 0;

int numOne[10]; 
int numTwo[10];

for(i=0;i<10;i++){ 
for(j=0;j<10;j++){ 
if((numOne[i]+numTwo[j]) == 10){ 
printf("%d\n",numOne[i]); 
printf("%d\n",numTwo[j]); 
} 
} 
}
```

Comment: You need to initialize values in the array. Though, you don't actually need arrays to begin with.

Comment: I'm no C expert but those arrays are empty

Comment: [tag:c], [tag:c#], and [tag:c++] are entirely different languages.  Don't spam tags.

Comment: The first thing that you're doing wrong is posting an unclear, poorly-formatted question with unrelated language tags.

Comment: You title should explain what you are asking. This could be something like "How to find the numbers that add up to 10" or "Using nested loops to find numbers up to 10".

Comment: Who upvoted this? How is this in any way a good question for SO?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need arrays

```
for(i=0;i<=10;i++){ 
   for(j=0;j<=10;j++){ 
      if(i+j == 10){ 
        printf("%d+%d\n",i,j); 
      } 
   }
}
```

Comment: Note, this won't print 10 and 0 which also adds up to 10.

Comment: Fixed the condition...

Comment: Nor will it print 1000 and -990, or 1.36 and 8.64, or ...  "Number" is a pretty broad category.